# How to establish external timeout for notify-rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use [notify-rust](https://github.com/hoodie/notify-rust) library on Ubuntu 20.04, but the notifications that are emitted have unpredictable timeouts. Also, if I send several notifications with short delays between them, the results may vary (sometimes I see all notifications, sometimes only several of them).

The workarounds I applied:

- Critical `Urgency`, so the notifications would stay displayed forever.
- Wait for an action before displaying the next notification, so no notifications would be lost.

```
// add `notify-rust = "4"` to dependencies for this code to work
use notify_rust::{Notification, Urgency};
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let summaries = ["one", "two"];

    for summary in summaries {
        let handle = Notification::new()
            .summary(summary)
            .urgency(Urgency::Critical)
            .show()
            .unwrap();

        // helps displaying all the notifications
        handle.wait_for_action(|_action| ());

        // delay might vary
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
}
```

I also experimented with the lib's `timeout`, but didn't get any good results.

The primary issue with the `wait_for_action` approach, is that sometimes no notification is seen on the screen after it was sent, so the main thread is waiting for an action on that notification that would never happen (nothing to click on).

I want to try a `watchdog` approach: start a thread, send the notification handler into it, and close the notification after some timeout:

```
let handle = Notification::new()
            ...

let thread_handle = handle.clone();

thread::spawn(move || {
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(60));
    thread_handle.close();
});

handle.wait_for_action(|_action| ());
```

I'm not sure how to do that part. I can't use `handle` both for the thread and for `wait_for_action`, because the thread takes the ownership. Cloning doesn't work properly, instead of `NotificationHandle` it produces `Notification`.

Is there any way to solve this without dip dig into `notify-rust` library internals?

I think I can resolve this using the whole different approach that won't involve calling blocking `wait_for_action`, but I wonder if there is any more elegant solution?

Comment: Might be a question for their issue tracker: https://github.com/hoodie/notify-rust/issues

Comment: Yep, the question is too specific maybe, but I feel it's more about Rust structures and async jobs. I'll repost it in the issue tracker a bit later.

Comment: For a record, I posted the issue: https://github.com/hoodie/notify-rust/issues/181

Answer (score 2):

I came up with another algorithm for notifications and timeouts: instead of relying on `wait_for_action` being able to catch an event of a notification being closed, I created two threads:

- one with the same `wait_for_action` that on completion sends a message through a channel
- another thread that waits for some time and then sends the same message through the same channel

The main thread waits for the message and continues as the first message arrives.

```
use notify_rust::{Notification, Urgency};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let summaries = ["one", "two"];

    for summary in summaries {
        // establish the channel and a second transmitter for `timeout` thread
        let (handler_tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let timer_tx = handler_tx.clone();

        // no changes here
        let handler = Notification::new()
            .summary(summary)
            .urgency(Urgency::Critical)
            .show()
            .unwrap();

        // `wait_for_action` is wrapped into a thread
        thread::spawn(move ||
            handler.wait_for_action(|_action|
                handler_tx.send(()).unwrap_or(())
            )
        );

        // another thread that waits and then sends the same message
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(7));
            timer_tx.send(()).unwrap_or(());
        });

        // the main thread that waits for a message from any of senders
        rx.recv().unwrap();

        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
}
```

Results of message sending are ignored on purpose: only one of those messages could be sent successfully, then the channel goes out of scope and another sender gets an error, and that's fine.

The solution has a disadvantage: it's possible that after the timeout, another notification would be sent without waiting for the previous one to be closed. I saw those notifications still can be displayed after the first one be closed even if the main thread finished, so they were waiting on the notification bus.

I also noted that there is another method implemented for `NotificationHandler` that probably suits better this task: [on_close](https://docs.rs/notify-rust/latest/notify_rust/struct.NotificationHandle.html#method.on_close), but it is implemented using `wait_for_action`, so it's also blocking, and I can't implement notification close after timeout using this method.